# ImportError: cannot import name 'empty_input_loss_func_wrapper' from 'detectron2.layers.wrappers'

Tags: python, detectron

My code below:

```
# COMMON LIBRARIES
import os
import cv2

from datetime import datetime

# DATA SET PREPARATION AND LOADING
from detectron2.data.datasets import register_coco_instances
from detectron2.data import DatasetCatalog, MetadataCatalog

# VISUALIZATION
from detectron2.utils.visualizer import Visualizer
from detectron2.utils.visualizer import ColorMode

# CONFIGURATION
from detectron2 import model_zoo
from detectron2.config import get_cfg

# EVALUATION
from detectron2.engine import DefaultPredictor

# TRAINING
from detectron2.engine import DefaultTrainer
```

Here are my versions:
Python 3.10.12
torch:  2.1 ; cuda:  rocm5.6
detectron2: 0.6

I tried changing python version to version 3.8 but still did not work

Comment: Could you provide the full error stack trace?